# Declare a variable and store retrieve data inside

Tags: json, angular, rest, ionic-framework

I have managed to retrieve data from Firebase, however, I am unable to store the data into a variable I have declared. I want to store in a variable is so that I am able to use at another method.

Please help.

These are the codes that I have tried.

1st method, rest api

```
retrieveUser(){
this.restProvider.retrieveUser(this.emailAdd, this.pw)
.subscribe(listUser => {
this.users = userList.results //trying to store to users variable
console.log(listUser);
},
err => {
console.log(err);
},
() => console.log('success')
);}
```

2nd method to use for some IF-ELSE

```
loginBtnPress(event){
this.retrieveUser();
console.log(this.users);
}
```

Comment: Why are you assigning userList.results in this.users? Your API data would be in listUser object, not in userList.results.

Comment: @Prachi sorry typo. but even though i put listUser, it still won't work. i still get 'undefined' out of `this.users`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. `this.users` is getting updated using `observables`. So, if you try to retrieve its value before the value has been updated, you wont get it as expected. You can call it as below,

```
retrieveUser(){
this.restProvider.retrieveUser(this.emailAdd, this.pw)
.subscribe(listUser => {
   this.users = userList.results //trying to store to users variable
   callYourMethodWithUpdatedValue(this.users); // <-- Pass value here
   },
   err => {
   console.log(err);
  },
  () => console.log('success')
  );}
```

The `callYourMethodWithUpdatedValue` is called every time(and as soon as) the value `this.users` is updated

#### Update 1

You can't retrieve async value in one method and expect that value to be used in some other method on button click. Reason being, your are expecting value on that button click , but since its a `async` call (can take `n` secs), you can't be assured that the value will be populated  when the value is used through some button call.

That's wrong implementation. You need to change the architecture to either of below:

1. Don't route to that page unless the `user` value has been resolved (received). Check `canActivate` and `canActivateChildren`.
2. Change the UX where you are trying to retrieve the use `async` variable on button click, and activate the button when the value has been received (Here you can use `Subject` ). [Something like this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/login-subject-exmaple?file=app%2Fsib1.component.html)

Comment: but what if i want to use the `this.users` at loginbtnPress method? is there a way to pass it?

Comment: @CodeName Then my friend, you need correct your implementation. Create a service and a `subject` inside it. Now, subscribe to the `Subject` inside other `components` who want to be aware of your changes. Take a look at a simple implementation. https://stackblitz.com/edit/subject-example?file=app%2Fcommon.svc.ts.

Comment: @CodeName , here the components are informed everytime the counter is increase. Similary you can create a subject for user login, which will notify respective `components` and `services`. Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, i have tried with the example you have linked here. However, i still don't understand. Because what I wanted is to just store retrieved data into a variable after using REST. Why do I need to do the `Subject` with `components` and subscribe it.

Comment: @CodeName Can you explain your scenario better in your question. If possible create a basic stackblitz.com example (just to get basic idea of flow)

Comment: The scenario is that I've a rest api method to retrieve a user data (incl. of e-mail and pw). Then i want to use that user data in another method (not my rest api method). So i tried to declare a variable called `users`. Then i tried to do `this.users = data`, however, it doesn't work because when i tried to do a `console.log(this.users)` on the not-my-rest-api method, it shows undefined. But at my rest api method, the data show it is retrieved

Comment: @CodeName Check my updated answer.If it has helped , please mark it as an answer as I have provided possible solution

Comment: @CodeName did it help u?